# Why does CLISP stops responding during this nested loop?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to create subsequences of some word with the following code.  When I added `by k`, the code stopped responding, though if I replace `k` with a particular number, it works.  What is happening?

```
(let ((c nil)) (loop for k from 0 to (length "abc")
     finally (return c) do (loop for j from 0 to (length "abc") by k 
    do (loop for i from j to (length "abc") do (push (subseq "abc" j i) c)))))
```

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Just hangs. Entering anything doesn't seem to complete it.

Comment: Often that's a sign of an infinite loop.  Given that this contains a number of `loops`, it'd be worthwhile to throw in some print statements and see what's happening.

Comment: @RainerJoswig : I tend to use eclipse for other languages and I forget that here in lisp it doesn't get indented automatically. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Debugging

> if I replace k with a particular number, it works

What happens if you replace `k` with `0`?

It would be much more helpful if you formatted this code with typical conventions, and probably if you isolated the particular part of the code that's problematic.  That is, `(remove-duplicates …)` isn't the problem here, you could have removed it.  With some more conventional formatting, and some comments, your code is:

```
(remove-duplicates
 (let ((c nil))
   (loop for k from 0 to (length "abc")                  ; k starts at 0
      finally (return c) 
      do (loop for j from 0 to (length "abc") by k       ; looping for j from 0 to something by k
            do (loop for i from j to (length "abc")
                  do (push (subseq "abc" j i) c)))))
 :test 'equal)
```

What's going to happen if you try to `loop for j from 0` to anything by `k`?  You're pretty much saying, "start with j at 0, then increment it by 0 for the next iteration…" so j never gets anywhere.  This really could have been caught with a `print` or `format`.  I know that's not the same as using a debugger, but sometimes the simplest ways are the quickest:

```
[8]> (remove-duplicates
 (let ((c nil))
   (loop for k from 0 to (length "abc")
      finally (return c) 
      do (loop for j from 0 to (length "abc") by k 
            do
              (format t "~&k: ~a, j: ~a" k j )
              (loop for i from j to (length "abc")
                 do (push (subseq "abc" j i) c)))))
 :test 'equal)
k: 0, j: 0
k: 0, j: 0
k: 0, j: 0
…
```

### Collecting subsequences

If you're trying to collect the subsequences of a given sequence, you might do it like this.  This works on both strings (vectors) and lists (although it's less efficient for lists).

```
(defun subsequences (sequence) 
  (loop
     with length = (length sequence)
     for i from 0 to length
     nconcing (loop 
                 for j from (1+ i) to length
                 collecting (subseq sequence i j))))
```

```
(subsequences "abc")
;=> ("a" "ab" "abc" "b" "c")

(subsequences '(1 2 3))
;=> ((1) (1 2) (1 2 3) (2) (2 3) (3))
```

---

---

### Appendex: A hard-to-understand error from SBCL

Interestingly, you'll get a runtime error with SBCL, although the error message doesn't make it particularly clear why.  Perhaps it's related to the infinite looping.

```
* (remove-duplicates
 (let ((c nil))
   (loop for k from 0 to (length "abc")
      finally (return c) 
      do (loop for j from 0 to (length "abc") by k 
            do
              (loop for i from j to (length "abc")
                 do (push (subseq "abc" j i) c)))))
 :test 'equal)

debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING
                                              {1002978E71}>:
  The value 0
  is not of type
    (OR (SINGLE-FLOAT (0.0)) (DOUBLE-FLOAT (0.0d0)) (RATIONAL (0))).

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

Comment: shall it not at least compile first to say that, it just doesn't stop accepting input, in case of other languages at least it complains, but I think u are correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you're trying to say.  I made a mistake in speaking about SBCL;  it does compile, but it gets a type-error pretty quickly.

Comment: @Rorschach I've also added some code that collects the subsequences of a sequence, which I think was the original question.  It (possibly) removes the need for `remove-duplicates`, too, depending on whether you want repeats for, e.g., repeated elements.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think `BY 0` should do in a loop?

```
(loop for i from 0 upto 10 by 0 do (princ '*))
```

If you are not advancing the variable, you'll get an endless loop.